# Can't get object with ReadAsAsync<T>

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Product class, which looks like this:

```
Public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public string InnerCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductUnit ProductUnit { get; set; }
    public int? ProductUnitID { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    public int? ProductTypeID { get; set; }

}
```

In ASP.NET Core Web API Service I have a put method which returns `OK(product)`.

The response in postman looks like this:

```
{
"result": {
    "id": 22,
    "name": "Bread",
    "productType": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Food",
        "remarks": null,
        "products": []
    },
    "productTypeID": 4,
    "code": "566",
    "barcode": "855",
    "innerCode": "145522",
    "productUnit": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Box",
        "remarks": null,
        "products": []
    },
    "productUnitID": 4
},
"id": 592,  ---> //probably this
"exception": null,
"status": 5,
"isCanceled": false,
"isCompleted": true,
"isCompletedSuccessfully": true,
"creationOptions": 0,
"asyncState": null,
"isFaulted": false
}
```

I am trying to get Product object as shown below:

```
var data = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
```

But As a result, I get the product object with null properties, except the ID, which is random number and which as I think is the id above the exception in the json response.

What mistake do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I believe you are trying to parse result which is the inner object in your case.
In order to parse the whole result you have to create a type for mentioned json, which you can create using https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp.

Classes will be as follows :

```
public partial class ProductResult
    {
        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public Result Result { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("exception")]
        public object Exception { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public long Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("isCanceled")]
        public bool IsCanceled { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("isCompleted")]
        public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("isCompletedSuccessfully")]
        public bool IsCompletedSuccessfully { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("creationOptions")]
        public long CreationOptions { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("asyncState")]
        public object AsyncState { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("isFaulted")]
        public bool IsFaulted { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Result
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("productType")]
        public Product ProductType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("productTypeID")]
        public long ProductTypeId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("code")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long Code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("barcode")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long Barcode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("innerCode")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long InnerCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("productUnit")]
        public Product ProductUnit { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("productUnitID")]
        public long ProductUnitId { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Product
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("remarks")]
        public object Remarks { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("products")]
        public List<object> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

now you can use ProductResult as

```
var data = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<ProductResult>();
```

**Update**

Another solution is, instead of creating type (class) for full JSON data you can use JObject class and using jsonpath you can select any property or object as follows :

```
string result = await  httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Product product = JObject.Parse(result).SelectToken("$.result").ToObject<Product>()
```